# call adminbar greeting in other place

Tags: php, admin-bar

I have disabled wordpress adminbar by adding this filter:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

But I still want to use it's greeting in other place.
By greeting I mean a dropdown menu which says: Howdy admin.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Use a conditional?

Comment: conditional? where and why?
I don't want to be using adminbar, only greeting portion

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. Top left bit? You could target it with CSS?

Comment: I know )) and some javascript. but whould be havy to call whole adminbar just because of that. That's why I prefer some PHP solution

Comment: Fair play. I'll think about it.

Comment: Looking at the filter you've mentioned, you do mean the admin bar on the front end of your website, correct? Also, where exactly would you like to have the new greeting displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, then you don't want to show other details than the greetings in the front end admina bar. If that is so then you can use **[Remove Node](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_node)** to make this work.

You can use it like below for only greetings and other options in it to display

First remove the below line

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Use the below in your active theme's **functions.php** file.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse_remove_node', 999 );
function wpse_remove_node( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'site-name' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'updates' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'comments' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-content' );
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'edit' );
}
```

The above will remove all the basic nodes from the admin bar from the front end and even if you have other nodes added due to plugins/theme, then you remove those using the same way.

Comment: I have searched other solutoins but this seem like the only way (didn't find this) thanks